# KeyError: 'geom_last' (for command "bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only")

Tags: python

According the api documents `bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only` can return 'geom_last'
Edges, Verts and faces.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=bmesh%20ops%20extrude_edge_only#bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only

When I run this code I get a key error.
I validated if the edges I want to extrude exist and they do.
I assume the extrude command runs it correct but does not return geom_last I think

Anyone who knows about this error and can explain me a little how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It's a Python error that is telling you that `ret` has no field called "geom_last".  If you share a Blend file that demonstrates the problem we might be able to tell you how to fix it; but there are several possible reasons. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: maybe use `print(k for k in ret)` to see what keys are available ?

Comment: @MartyFouts When running the command Gorgious points out this it the result " <generator object add_mesh.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001723F8EFF90>"

Comment: Try `print([k for k in ret])` instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and help. The issue was that it does NOT return "geom_last" but "geom". Next time i just need to read proper and be patient while reading..... Apologies everyone. thansk to @MarkusvonBroady for the command coz that showed me what it should be and after that I checked the API docs again :[-)